# How to pause video automatically after 10 seconds in video.js?

Tags: wordpress, video.js

I want to pause a video automatically after playing 10 seconds.

Here is HTML code

```
<video id="video_kgvid_0" controls preload="metadata" 
 poster="video poster url" width="640" height="267" class="fitvidsignore video-js kg-
 video-js-skin">
 <source src="video url" type="video/mp4" data-res="534p">
 </video>
```

So far tried this JS code

```
var pausetime = 10; 

var myPlayer = videojs('video_kgvid_0');

myPlayer.on('timeupdate', function (e) {
    if (myPlayer.currentTime() >= pausetime) {
        myPlayer.pause();
    }
});

myPlayer.play();
```

Please be noted that I am using a plugin called "Video Embed & Thumbnail Generator" on a WordPress site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can try this

```
   var pausetime = 10; 

var myPlayer = videojs('video_kgvid_0');

myPlayer.on('timeupdate', function (e) {
    if (myPlayer.currentTime() >= pausetime) {
        myPlayer.pause();
        pausetime = Number(myPlayer.currentTime()) + 10;
    }
});

myPlayer.play();
```

Comment: Not working either. Instead of pausing the video, I will be okay with if the video DIV can be hidden and show a popup.

Comment: i think its working i have tested . i will send you demo in few minutes

Comment: Please check on below link i have did for 2 seconds 

http://jsfiddle.net/EdjxN/240/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=EdjxN

Comment: Perfect. I will try it on Wordpress. Do you have any idea to implement hide() to hide the video div right after pausing?

Comment: yes its simple  add in if condition  $('#divID').hide();

Comment: Never forget to VOTE up to my answer :)   Thank you . i am here if any issue

Comment: Added $('video-js-box').hide(); but didn't hide. What's wrong?

Comment: $('#video-js-box').hide();

hash was missing

Comment: if wordpress then use /////

Comment: jQuery('#video-js-box').hide();

Comment: jQuery('#video-js-box').remove();

Comment: video-js-box  should be id of the div

Comment: Awesome.  Nice to hear

Comment: One more thing...It works only when a user logged in. Do you know why?

Comment: It can be your browser cache